# XML output with element value as tag name and next subsequent element value as value for the created tag

Tags: xslt, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to form an output xml in which I need to have the field value as a tag and then the subsequent next field value as value for the created tag.

```
<PrimaryKey>
    <PK1FeildName>CONNO</PK1FeildName>
    <PK1Value>001</PK1Value>
    <PK2FeildName>INNO</PK2FeildName>
    <PK2Value>123</PK2Value>
    <PK3FeildName>CONNO</PK3FeildName>
    <PK3Value>011</PK3Value>
</PrimaryKey>
```

Expected output:

```
<PrimaryKey>
  <CONNO>001</CONNO>
  <INNO>123</INNO>
  <CONNO>011</CONNO>
</PrimaryKey>
```

Comment: I notice that you have added the 'esql' tag to this post. Are you using IBM Integration Bus?

Comment: Yes, I am using IBM integration bus but I have been trying to implement a logic by reading the field name capturing it in output tree structure but I am not able to fetch the tag and it's respective value as required... As of now I have worked on implementing the logic for field name and values in two different tree structures but later again I will have to compare it at the substring level , I am not sure how to take this further

Comment: Note that `field` is spelled thusly and not `feild`.  Whether that's a factor in your problem is for you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that the elements will always appear in pairs where the value of the first element is the tag name and the second element is the value, then this works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="PrimaryKey">
      <xsl:element name="PrimaryKey">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*) mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can try it here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdws3

**Edit to answer comment**

Example XML :

```
<Document>
    <PrimaryKey>
        <PK1FeildName>CONNO</PK1FeildName>
        <PK1Value>001</PK1Value>
        <PK2FeildName>INNO</PK2FeildName>
        <PK2Value>123</PK2Value>
        <PK3FeildName>CONNO</PK3FeildName>
        <PK3Value>011</PK3Value>
    </PrimaryKey>
    <PrimaryKey>
        <PK1FeildName>CONNO2</PK1FeildName>
        <PK1Value>0012</PK1Value>
        <PK2FeildName>INNO2</PK2FeildName>
        <PK2Value>1232</PK2Value>
        <PK3FeildName>CONNO2</PK3FeildName>
        <PK3Value>0112</PK3Value>
    </PrimaryKey>
</Document>
```

Modified XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="PrimaryKey">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PrimaryKey/*">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*) mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdws3/1

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, just I needed to ask you how does it work if I have multiple occurance of primarykey tag, do I need to mention the template with the main root tag name? Just wanted to have an understanding on template working as I am a beginner for Xslt.            <Root><PrimaryKey>
    <PK1FeildName>CONNO</PK1FeildName>
    <PK1Value>001</PK1Value>
    <PK2FeildName>INNO</PK2FeildName>
    <PK2Value>123</PK2Value>             </PrimaryKey>      
  <PrimaryKey>
    <PK3FeildName>CONNO</PK3FeildName>
    <PK3Value>011</PK3Value>
</PrimaryKey></Root>

Comment: See my modified answer to take into account XML that would have more than one <PrimaryKey>.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Sebastian, Just one question for my learning does following-sibling::*[1] acts as the value of the particular field being read in the loop?

Comment: In the match="PrimaryKey/*" template, the if statement checks if the element's position is an even number (i.e. first element of a pair). The following-sibling::*[1] statement selects the next element's value. So the first element becomes the node's name and the second element becomes the value.

Comment: If your question is answered, please close it by accepting the answer.

Comment: This constant counting of preceding siblings is expensive; use `position()` instead. And you can apply templates selectively to the first node in a pair instead of testing each one. Or you can use the last part of the name to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a solution that uses ESQL instead of XSLT:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    -- Get a reference to the first instance of 'PK1FeildName'
    DECLARE refPK REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC.PrimaryKey.PK1FeildName[1];
    WHILE LASTMOVE(refPK) DO
        -- remember the field name 
        DECLARE keyName CHARACTER FIELDVALUE(refPK);
        MOVE refPK NEXTSIBLING;

        -- create the next field in the output
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Document.PrimaryKey TYPE NameValue NAME keyName VALUE FIELDVALUE(refPK);
        MOVE refPK NEXTSIBLING;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN TRUE;
END;
```

Whether you use XSL or ESQL, I would recommend that you validate the incoming XML against an XSD because the mapping code depends on seeing specific tags in a specific order. You could add code to check the tag names, but XSD validation is a much easier solution.

Comment: Thank you Kimbert, this was very helpful.